# Jira Errors with Calculated Number Field

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We try to calculate a WSJF Number for internal priorization of Issues based on 7 variables which can be choosed in dropdowns (customfileds).

the calculation works and the calculated number field with the wsjf number can be seen.
but the formula seems somehow making constant errors in the logs and our jira instance even broke down because of the log file getting so big.

the Formula for the calculation is:

```
 <!-- @@Formula:

    //Constants
    var a = 0.3; // Strategical alignment (sa) and Revenue potential (rp) are weighted 30%
    var b = 0.2; // Saving potential (sp) and competitive advantage (ca) are weighted 20%
    var x = 2; // Is the factor for the weight of "business value" (bv) in the model
    var y = 1; // Is the factor for the weight of the "loss of value" (lv) in the model
    var z = 1; // Is the factor for the weight of the "capacity increase" (ci) in the model

    //Variables for business value
    var sa = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11631") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11631") : 0);
    var rp = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11632") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11632") : 0);
    var sp = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11633") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11633") : 0);
    var ca = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11634") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11634"): 0);
    var bv = (sa+rp)*a + (sp+ca)*b;

    //Variables for loss of value over time
    var lv = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11635") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11635") : 0);

    //Variables for capacity increase
    var ci = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11636") != null ? issue.get("customfield_11636") : 0);

    //Variables for investment
    var in = Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11637") != null ? (issue.get("customfield_11637") : 0);

    //WSJF calculation
    var wsjf = (x*bv+y*lv+z*ci)/in;

       return wsjf;

    -->
```

the Errors from the logfile look like:

```
2015-05-06 14:16:40,133 http-bio-443-exec-866 ERROR Andreas Kundert 856x2705040x1 41jq3d 192.168.37.39:63202,192.168.211.105 /secure/AjaxIssueAction.jspa [innovalog.jmcf.fields.CalculatedNumberField] CalculatedNumberField: error evaluating formula of field "WSJF (automated)" of issue BI-24: 
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    //Constants  var a = 0.3; // Strategical alignment (s) and Revenue potential . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt : at Line: 11 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``    //Constants  var a = 0.3; // Strategical alignment (s) and Revenue potential . . . '' : Integer .parseInt ( issue .get ( "customfield_11631" ) )
```

or

```
CalculatedNumberField: error evaluating formula of field "WSJF (automated)" of issue LIAR-101: 
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    //Constants  var a = 0.3; // Strategical alignment (s) and Revenue potential . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method parseInt( int ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer' : at Line: 11 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``    //Constants  var a = 0.3; // Strategical alignment (s) and Revenue potential . . . '' : Integer .parseInt ( issue .get ( "customfield_11631" ) != null ? issue .get ( "customfield_11631" ) : 0 )
```

Comment: In the part where you;re trying to get value from customfield, you probably need to use something like `getValue()`.

Comment: I tried that, but then the Calculation does nothing and returns the same error. where should i put the getValue() into?

Comment: Maybe try `int i = (issue.get("customfield_11631") != null ? Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11631").toString()) : 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int i = (issue.get("customfield_11631") != null ? Integer.parseInt(issue.get("customfield_11631").toString()) : 0)` made it work.
great thanks @[ThePavolC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229132/thepavolc)